# App Structure for a SPA - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, single-page-application, mean-stack

I have a MEAN Stack app which was previously a Server Based Application and now I am trying to convert it to a Single Page Application.

**My Current Structure:**

- I have an index.ejs file which loads the main view and it contains the `ng-view` tag.
- The index.ejs file has a menu with 5 items. Each item loads a new view inside the ng-view.
- Each menu item loads a new view and each of them have their own controllers.

**My Issue:**

Currently all my functionality is under a single controller so when I use ngRoute it looks like this:

```
myCtrl.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/test.ejs',
            controller: 'myCtrl1',
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/proposals', {
            templateUrl: '/profile.ejs',
            controller: 'myCtrl1'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/bios', {
            templateUrl : '/test2.ejs',
            controller  : 'myCtrl1'
        }); 
});
```

This is causing my controller file to a lot of code. I want to divide them based on their features. So each view should have its own controller.

**My Questions:**

1. Whats the correct app structure for this type of scenario.
2. How can I place external controllers into the ngRoute like so:

   ```
       myApp.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope){});

       .when('/', {
           templateUrl: '/test.ejs',
           controller: 'myCtrl1', // INTERNAL CONTROLLER
       })


       .when('/proposals', {
           templateUrl: '/profile.ejs',
           controller: '/directory2/js/myCtrl2' //EXTERNAL CONTROLLER
       })
   ```

**I am not sure whats the right approach here. I want to make my app modular and have separation of concern.**

Comment: I think you should have one, the most abstract, `MainCtrl` Which is defined on the `div` wrapping your `ng-view` or `body` tag, and each view would have it's own separate controller.

Comment: @notgiorgi could you provide an example please?

Comment: Okay, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Have you checked out the mean.js or mean.io frameworks

Answer (score 0):

If you use component-based architecture like described [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules), you can have following structure:

**router**:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute', 'dashboard', 'calendar'])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        template: '<dashboard></dashboard>',
        controller: function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.name = "Dashboard";
        }

    }).when('/calendar', {
        template: '<calendar></calendar>',
        controller: function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.name = "Calendar events";
        }

    }).otherwise('/dashboard');
}
])
```

and then your Dashboard can be:

```
angular.
module('dashboard').
component('dashboard', {
    controller: DashboardController,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html'

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Any chance you can provide a working example? Im still a little confused.

Comment: @Lorenzo It'll be something like https://jsfiddle.net/jtx06r0p/
I'm trying this example to work on JSFiddle, but have some problems.